# Laravel 6.2 : $request->all() return a empty array

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, request, laravel-6.2

I used Postman to send request in my Laravel Api and I have a empty array to return. And I don't know why ?

My Route :

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group( function () {

    Route::resource('reservations', 'ReservationController');
});
```

My reservationController :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\ReservationCreateRequest;
use App\Repositories\ReservationRepository;
use App\Http\Resources\Reservation as ReservationResource;

class ReservationController extends BaseController
{

    protected $entrepriseRepository;

    public function __construct(ReservationRepository $reservationRepository)
    {
        $this->reservationRepository = $reservationRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $reservation = $this->reservationRepository->getById($id);

        return $this->sendResponse(new ReservationResource($reservation), 'Reservation');
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $inputs = $request->all();

        if (!$reservation = $this->reservationRepository->update($id, $inputs))
         {
         return $this->sendError('Impossible de mettre à jour', $request->errors(), 400);
        }

        return $this->sendResponse(new ReservationResource($reservation), 'Reservation mise à jour avec succès !' , 200);
    }
}
```

if I return just a response with

```
return response($request->all());
```

I have a empty array...

The method

```
show($id)
```

works correctly...

Any suggestions someone ?

Comment: Show us how you're sending the request in Postman. `$id` is not part of `$request->all()` if you're looking for it in there.

Comment: What is `sendResponse()`? Please can you show the code for it.

Comment: do you send `api_token` in your request ?

Answer (score 7):

If you're sending `PATCH` request from postman, you need to send it with `x-www-form-urlencoded` as Laravel unfortunately gives empty request for `form-data` with `PATCH` request.

As a side note, you can't send files with `x-www-form-urlencoded` so if you have files in your request, you should send a `POST` request using `form-data` and `_method: PATCH` in the request body, Laravel will automatically treat it like a `PATCH` request.

Comment: That's it ! Thanks a lot... ;)

Comment: I know it's a pretty old question, but is this rule only for PATCH requests? Also, been stuck here for a whole day! Thank you.